# Class derived from CEdit does not take any numeric value

Tags: mfc

I am new to MFC. I created Edit Box dynamically by generating my own `CEdit` class which is `CMYEditEx` it has created the edit box on dialog but it does not take any numeric value. I want to make edit box only for numeric value. 
i am not able to write any things in edit box but my purpose is to create edit box which only take numeric values . this function is implemented in OnItDlg

```
CMYEditEx* pEdit = new CMYEditEx;

    pEdit->Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_NUMBER ,
        CRect(130, aSize, 260, bSize), this, 1);


BOOL CMYEditEx::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class



    int  nTextLength = this->GetWindowTextLength();
    if (pMsg->message == WM_CHAR)
    {
        // Ignoring 0 to 9
        if ((pMsg->wParam >= '0' &&   pMsg->wParam <= '9'))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to write anything into the edit control? Please [edit]  your question and be more specific. What happens _exactly_? What do you expect to happen _exactly_? Where did you put the piece of code you show here? In `OnInitDialog`, in the constructor? Somewhere else? We cannot know, you need to tell us. Show more relevant code.

Comment: is there any solution for it . i derived CMYEditEx class from CEdit and then create Edit control as shown above  in another class in OnItDialog function. i want to make this Edit box only for numeric values

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What happens if you enter a letter (A,B,C)? What happens if you enter a digit (1,2,3) ? What exactly does not work? Also you need to show more code. Is there a `delete pEdit;` somewhere? If it's in the wrong place you'll get into trouble. Post the relevant code.

Comment: It would also be important to know what you are doing in your derived class `CMYEditEx`. The relevant code should be posted in the question. The problem propably is in the code you are not showing.

Comment: Edit box allow to enter character but did not allow me to enter numeric value

Comment: BOOL CTabTwo::OnInitDialog()
{
 CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
 
  CMYEditEx* pEdit = new CMYEditEx;
  
  pEdit->Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_NUMBER ,
   CRect(130, 20, 260, 40), this, 1);
 

  

 
 return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
      // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
} this is the code which in written in class of CTabTwo generated from CDialogEx and CMyEdit is the class which is generated form CEdit.

Comment: I asked for code of `CMYEditEx` itself, not how you create it. Also please don't post code as comment as it is very unreadable and hard to find for future readers, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51103377/edit) the question to include the relevant code.

Comment: sorry sir and thanks for help i got the error actually the problem was in CMYEditEx you can see in the question.

Comment: `WM_CHAR` is the wrong message to handle, when you are interested in changes to the control's text. After all, you can change the contents, without typing anything (e.g. by pasting from the clipboard). Handle [EN_CHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/en-change) (or friends) instead. Besides that `PreTranslateMessage` is called *prior* to calling `TranslateMessage`. It's `TranslateMessage` that actually generates `WM_CHAR` messages based on raw input.